# Its all about CLR Hosting

Tags: c#, .net

Why we need CLR Hosting? Can I do CLR Hosting using C#? If yes then please give an example.

Comment: Partial duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348207/what-is-clr-hosting

Answer (score 6):

CLR hosting is when you have a native application which wants to run the CLR within the same process. It makes no sense to talk about CLR hosting using C#, as you're already *running* the CLR if you're running C# code (beyond some very strange situations).

Basically, if you need to ask about it, you almost certainly don't need to do it.

See [MSDN for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380850.aspx).