# C# system.stackoverflow exception

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, stack-overflow

I'm getting a stackoverflow exception on a if/else statement..

Example of code:

```
if (driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='modal']/div/div/div/p[contains(text(), 'Hello World')]")).Count != 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}
else
{
    RunOtherFunction();
}
```

highlighted error code is -

```
if (driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='modal']/div/div/div/p[contains(text(), 'Hello World')]")).Count != 0)
```

so clearly it's throwing a exception due to not finding the specified element but I have that covered with an else statement?

so I don't understand why it's throwing an exception because if Element isn't found then it should execute  " RunOtherFunction(); " instead it's throwing exception?

Comment: @DebanjanB this is c# lol

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: I don't think selenium would throw a StackOverflowException just because it can't find an element by xpath. Are you using some recursion? Is RunOtherFunction calling the function you're trying to find element by xpath? I think we might need to see some more code to help.

Answer (score 0):

The highlighted row is correct. It throws exception on the first line and since you don't have a try catch block it won't go into the else.

Comment: if the exception is truly a StackOverflowException, you (generally) can't catch it anyways. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1599238/1224272

Comment: I know that. My point is that from the provided info, I doubt that really a StackOverflow exception is thrown. I believe ElementNotFoundException is thrown or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

*An Answer based on Java perspective :*

I did a small test with the similar usecase where :

- I opened the url `https://www.google.com/`
- Used `findElements()` to find elements with `id` as **Rs_Sele** on the page in a `if-else {}` loop and used `!=` operator to compare with **0**
- Here is the sample code :

  ```
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
  if(driver.findElements(By.id("Rs_Sele")).size() !=0)
      System.out.println("Atleast one element was found");
  else
      System.out.println("No element was found");
  ```
- Console Output :

  ```
  No element was found
  ```

### Analysis

- The *Java Docs* of [**findElements()**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-) mentions that this method finds all elements within the current context using the provided mechanism. This method will return as soon as there are more than 0 items in the found collection or will return an **empty list** if the timeout is reached.
- So the `findElements()` method returned an **empty list** and after the comparision the control went to the `else {}` block and printed **No element was found**.
- The same happened with your code block as well.
- `driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='modal']/div/div/div/p[contains(text(), 'Hello World')]"))` returned an **empty list**
- After the comparision through **!=** operator with **0** `else {}` block was executed and subsequently `RunOtherFunction()` function was invoked.

### Conclusion

If you are observing **stackoverflow exception** it is because of the function **RunOtherFunction();**

### References

You can find similar discussions on *StackOverflowException* in :

- [**C# catch a stack overflow exception**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599219/c-sharp-catch-a-stack-overflow-exception)
- [**C# cannot catch StackOverflowException or see where it happened**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897083/c-sharp-cannot-catch-stackoverflowexception-or-see-where-it-happened?noredirect=1&lq=1)